# how to calculate the difference between cells in the same column?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to calculate the difference between the cells in the 'Sum of Backorders YTD' column for the specific region and in between the months, if that makes sense.

How would I be able to do that?

I have attached a photo for better understanding.

[image]

I tried using CALCULATE and SUM with FILTERS to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data looks like the table below, I added an additional column to store the month field as a date field.

| Item Group | Month | FullMonth | Reg | BackOrders YTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 1 | 01 January 2022 | B | 14 |
| 9 | 2 | 01 February 2022 | B | 9 |
| 9 | 3 | 01 March 2022 | B | 15 |
| 9 | 4 | 01 April 2022 | B | 6 |
| 9 | 1 | 01 January 2022 | C | 202 |
| 9 | 2 | 01 February 2022 | C | 42 |
| 9 | 3 | 01 March 2022 | C | 94 |
| 9 | 4 | 01 April 2022 | C | 87 |

## Offset

You can use `OFFSET` to access the previous row, indicating the calculation context.

### DAX Calculation: Offset

```
Previous Month BackOrders YTD = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[BackOrders YTD] ),
    OFFSET (
        -1,
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Table'[Item Group], 'Table'[Reg], 'Table'[Month] ),
        ORDERBY ( 'Table'[Item Group], ASC, 'Table'[Reg], ASC, 'Table'[Month], ASC ),
        DEFAULT,
        PARTITIONBY ( 'Table'[Item Group], 'Table'[Reg] )
    ),
    ALLSELECTED ()
)
```

### Output

[image]

## Time Intelligence

Although a better way is creating a Calendar table and using Time Intelligence to calculate the previous month's value.
It's necessary to indicate what's the context creating filters for each dimension placed in your table that creates a partition. In this case, `REG` AND `Item Group`.

### Calendar Table

```
Calendar =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALENDARAUTO (),
    "MonthStart", DATE ( YEAR ( [Date] ), MONTH ( [Date] ), 01 )
)
```

### Dax Calculation: Time Intelligence

```
Previous Month BackOrders YTD (TimeIntelligence) =
VAR _SelectedItemGroup =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Item Group] )
VAR _SelectedReg =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Reg] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[BackOrders YTD] ),
        PREVIOUSMONTH ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
        'Table'[Item Group] = _SelectedItemGroup,
        'Table'[Reg] = _SelectedReg,
        ALL ()
    )
```

## Output

[image]